oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed in RHEL 8 with HTTPD
I need your help to connect to Oracle in PHP8 on my Red Hat 8.9 server.
OCI8 is enabled and the HTTPD web server is installed. This is my code:
    <?php
    // Enable error reporting in PHP
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
    // Connect to the Oracle database using oci_connect
    $conn = oci_connect("toakdbi", "toakdbi_123", "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=AvaniServer)(PORT=1521)))(CONNE_DATA=(SID=orcl)))");
    
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e['message'];
    } else {
        echo "</br>Connected to Oracle!";
    }
    ?>

This is the error I got:
Warning: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in /var/www/html/db2.php on line 10 
Warning: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804 in /var/www/html/db2.php on line 10 
Warning: Trying to access array offset on false in /var/www/html/db2.php on line 14
Connection failed:


My config is below:
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib
SetEnv NLS_LANG American_America.UTF8
SetEnv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/bin
PassEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/etc/sysconfig/httpd
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/bin

~/.bashrc
# .bashrc   
# User specific aliases and functions   
    
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib
export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8
export TNS_ADMIN=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/network/admin
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

~/.bash_profile
#.bash_profile
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=orcl

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib
export NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8
export TNS_ADMIN=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/network/admin
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:.
# User specific environment and startup programs



export PATH

/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/httpd.conf
[Service]
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib"
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/bin"


Did you try from the command line (CLI PHP instead of web)?

@Olivier yes i tried , with curl -v http://10.101010/dbconnect.php . getting same error.  but if i tried to connect with php dbconnect.php i got success message. on terminal

You could try using putenv() to set the environment variables.

@Olivier yes this one also tried still getting same issue

Maybe the web user has no permission to access the instantclient directory.

@Olivier i given 775 or 777 for instantclient path

@Olivier drwxr-xr-x. 3 apache apache 4096 Sep  9 07:28 /home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib/instantclient

You have a small misspelling in your code, it should be CONNECT_DATA instead of CONNE_DATA.
// Connect to the Oracle database using oci_connect
$conn = oci_connect("toakdbi", "toakdbi_123", "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=AvaniServer)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))");


Never set ORACLE_HOME when using Oracle Instant Client.  Also, with Instant Client, setting ORACLE_SID doesn't make sense.  So unset these.  Try using the ldconfig command as mentioned in the installation doc instead of setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Your path /home/oracle/Avani/dbhome_1/lib/instantclient looks suspicious.  If you have installed the database, then you don't need to install Instant Client.  The DB /lib directory already has the correct libraries.
Overall I recommend installing the Instant Client RPM instead of the Instant Client ZIP. The RPM will set the library search path correctly as part of its install.  Then you can unset all the Oracle environment variables.  Passing the environment variables through Apache gets tricky since you need to put them in the correct file.  Setting the variables in your shell is generally not sufficient and won't work

hii I updated question, please check

Still missing is what Oracle libraries you have installed - is it a DB or a full client (installed with Oracle's GUI), or an Instant Client install?  Then does  PHP work in the command line?  If so, replicate that shell environment in whatever config files your web server version needs.  From memory /etc/sysconfig/httpd is the file that is used.  Up above your different  files have different variables set.  Triple check /home/oracle is readable to other processes
